# How to randomly mix two PyTorch tensors

Tags: list, pytorch, tensor

I have two same-shaped PyTorch tensors A and B, and I'd like to create a same-shape "randomly mixed" tensor C where C[i,...] = A[i,...] with probability alpha or B[i,...] with probability 1-alpha.  Is there some Pythonic way to do this compactly?

Answer (score 6):

consider using `torch.bernoulli` to create a mask tensor:

```py
import torch

prob = 0.8
x = torch.full((2, 6, 3), 10.2, dtype=torch.float)
y = torch.full((2, 6, 3), -1.6, dtype=torch.float)

mask = torch.bernoulli(torch.full(x.shape, prob)).int()
reverse_mask = torch.ones(x.shape).int() - mask

result = x * mask + y * reverse_mask
```

`result` is now:

```py
[[[10.2000, 10.2000, 10.2000],
[10.2000, -1.6000, 10.2000],
[10.2000, 10.2000, -1.6000],
[-1.6000, 10.2000, -1.6000],
[10.2000, 10.2000, 10.2000],
[10.2000, 10.2000, 10.2000]],
[[10.2000, 10.2000, -1.6000],
[10.2000, 10.2000, 10.2000],
[10.2000, 10.2000, -1.6000],
[10.2000, -1.6000, 10.2000],
[-1.6000, 10.2000, 10.2000],
[10.2000, 10.2000, 10.2000]]]
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I think OP wants to pick from the first dimension only. But the idea is pretty much the same. Aslo, `reverse_mask = 1 - mask` should work as well.

Comment: Hmmm...  Trying out suggestion, there appears to be more mixing than I would like, perhaps going along the lines @Quang Hoang indicates.  But, I'm not following the "pretty much the same" part.

Comment: @MarkLavin use `mask = torch.bernoulli(torch.full(x.shape[:1], 0.8))[:,None,None]`.